# sorting an ul list according to a li element with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, list, sorting

I'm creating a horizontal list with < ul > element but what I want to do is to put each < ul > element in alphabetical order according to a < li > element. For example

```
<ul class="list">
    <li>Name</li>
    <li>Surname</li>
    <li>Unit</li>
    <li>City</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li>John</li>
    <li>Boe</li>
    <li>B.A.</li>
    <li>NY</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
    <li>Jane</li>
    <li>Doe</li>
    <li>M.A.</li>
    <li>CA</li>
</ul>
```

and put them in order according to Surname field. Is there any way to do this with jquery?

Thanks in advance

//EDIT//

The code I'm using is something like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'list.php',
    data: 'id='+id,
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(data) {
        var xml;
        if (typeof data == "string") {
            xml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
            xml.async = false;
            xml.loadXML(data);
        } else {
            xml = data;
        }

        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
            var id = $(this).find("id").text();
            var name = $(this).find("name").text();
            var surname = $(this).find("surname").text();
            var units = $(this).find("units").text();
            var city = $(this).find("city").text();
            $("#listContainer").append('<ul class="list" id="'+id+'"><li style="width:30px;">'+name+'</li><li style="width:100px;">'+surname+'</li><li style="width:100px;">'+units+'</li><li style="width:100px;">'+city+'</li></ul>');
        }); //close each(   
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you paste the code that you have attempted?

Comment: You realise that this looks more like tabular data?

Comment: Yes it seems like tabular data but I didn't want to use tables at first and I built the whole page depending on it, now my client wants me to make an advanced sorting option and I've thought that would be the bast solution if I could sort each < ul > element somehow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/eWxHQ/)

```
$('.grid ul:gt(0)').each(function() {
    var txt1 = $(this).children('li:eq(1)').text();
    $(this).data('name', txt1);
});

var items = $('.grid ul');
items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var chA = $(a).data('name');
    var chB = $(b).data('name');
    if (chA < chB) return -1;
    if (chA > chB) return 1;
    return 0;
});
var grid = $('.grid');
$(grid).append(items);
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="grid">
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Surname</li>
        <li>Unit</li>
        <li>City</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>John</li>
        <li>Boe</li>
        <li>B.A.</li>
        <li>NY</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Jane</li>
        <li>Doe</li>
        <li>M.A.</li>
        <li>CA</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Lin</li>
        <li>Zyan</li>
        <li>M.A.</li>
        <li>OR</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="list">
        <li>Matt</li>
        <li>Albright</li>
        <li>M.A.</li>
        <li>CA</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Will result in:

[image]

How it works:
We look for the text inside the desired `li` `:eq()`
and we set this text as a jQuery .data() for each UL element.
Than we just sort the `ul` by the retrieved .data() text - alphabetically!

Happy coding!

Comment: Please check this jsfiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/Kaushik007/qtbc9mt0/                                                                                        When click on checkbox,  i want ul > li > first div text Should be Ascending.

The country div text should not be ascending It should stay as it is.          
This code is working but not as per my requirement.                         Thanks In Advance.

Comment: @K-Series your requirement is odd. You're sorting elements containing multiple stuff but you expect it to magically keep those other elements- *in the initial place*. Than don't put them in the same container-list in the first place. Hope it makes sense. The purpose of sorting is exactly to - sort a single list, not to do fancy stuff with child content... You could write a Question that describes what you're actually after...