# divide a single list in a number of columns but is not in order

Tags: jquery, html

here is the code

```
var cols = 3;
var container = $('ul');
var items = container.find('li');
var itemsPerCol = Math.ceil(items.length / cols);
var stack = []; 
for (var i = 0; i < itemsPerCol; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
        stack.push(items[i + (itemsPerCol * k)]);
    }
}
items.css({
    float:'left',
    width:Math.floor(container.width() / cols)
});
container.html(stack).append($('<br>').css({clear:'both'}));
```

There are 16 lists in there, and its not in order but when I make it to 15 list it is in order

here is the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8jbNR/)

I just need it to be in order in anyway possible because a list will always be added.

Comment: have a look at this .. http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/eWxHQ/39/

Comment: @user1145009 how is this Q related to my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406220/sorting-an-ul-list-according-to-a-li-element-with-jquery ?

Comment: thanks user1145009, but the list is coming from wordpress, so you cannot alter the HTML code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cols = 3;
var container = $('ul');
var items = container.find('li');
var itemsPerCol = Math.ceil(items.length / cols);
var stack = []; 
var containerWidth = container.width();
for (var i = 0; i < itemsPerCol; i++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
        if((i + (itemsPerCol * k)) < items.length)
        {
            var item = items[i + (itemsPerCol * k)];
            item.style.width = containerWidth / cols + 'px';
            item.style.float = 'left';
            stack.push(item);    
        }
        else
        {
            var item = stack.pop(item);
            item.style.width = ((containerWidth / cols) * k) + 'px';
            stack.push(item);   
        }
    }
}

container.html(stack).append($('<br>').css({clear:'both'}));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/8jbNR/9/)

Comment: hi, i have increased the list to 22 and it turned out to be not in order again Abhishek Jain

Comment: Updated the code please check, the problem was with the container width so i changed the approach