# Disappearing list items when sorting/searching w/ list.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, list

I've built a location search widget using list.js here: http://tonic-agencyhq.co.uk/locations.php

The problem is whenever I search/sort all of the list items disappear. It works fine if I add items in as actual HTML elements but I'm currently using some jQuery+JSON to generate the items.

The code I have used:

```html
<div id="locations">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search" />
  <button class="sort" data-sort="location-title">Sort by Title</button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="organisation">Sort by Organisation</button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="city">Sort by City</button>
  <ul class="list" id="locations-list"></ul>
</div>

<script src="content/themes/tui/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    var $locations = $("#locations-list");
 
    $.getJSON("content/themes/tui/assets/json/locations.json", function (locations) {
        $.each(locations, function(i, loc) {
            var $li = $("<li><h3 class='location-title'>" + loc["Location Title"] + "</h3><p class='organisation'>" + loc["Organisation"] + "</p><p class='address'>" + loc["Address"] + "</p><span class='city'>" + loc["City"] + "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class='postcode'>" + loc["Postcode"] + "</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class='country'>" + loc["Country"] + "</span></li>");
            $locations.append($li);
        });
    }); 

</script>

<script src="content/themes/tui/assets/js/list.min.js"></script>

<script>

var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'location-title', 'organisation' , 'city' ]
};

var locationsList = new List('locations', options);

</script>
```

Comment: Are you looking for how to sort, Ul/Li, then you can check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406220/sorting-an-ul-list-according-to-a-li-element-with-jquery

Comment: Please post the click listeners for you buttons.

Comment: @Samurai would the click listeners be created by the list.js? I'm not too familiar with what click listeners are tbh so I'm sort of confused.

Comment: @AnilKumar I am able to sort fine when all the items in the list are coded right into the html. if you see, I've added a "test" item to the top of the list that doesn't disappear when you try to sort or search. I need all the other list items that have been generated to function this way rather than vanish upon searching/sorting.

Comment: Can you please show how are you sorting, request to add code for Sort function also?

Comment: @AnilKumar Well here is list.js that I'm pulling through: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/javve/list.js/v1.1.1/dist/list.js Can the sort function be found here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>

var $locations = $("#locations-list");

$.getJSON("content/themes/tui/assets/json/locations.json", function (locations) {
    $.each(locations, function(i, loc) {
        var $li = $("<li><h3 class='location-title'>" + loc["Location Title"] + "</h3><p class='organisation'>" + loc["Organisation"] + "</p><p class='address'>" + loc["Address"] + "</p><span class='city'>" + loc["City"] + "&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class='postcode'>" + loc["Postcode"] + "</span>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<span class='country'>" + loc["Country"] + "</span></li>");
        $locations.append($li);
    });

var options = {


 valueNames: [ 'location-title', 'organisation' , 'city' ]
};

var locationsList = new List('locations', options);
});
```

Your Ajax call is asynchronous here, move list creation inside this. The dynamic list ($locations.append()) are not getting passed to list.js. That is why you only seeing staically created UL after sort and not dynamically created.

Comment: Brilliant, it works! Thank you :) I'm now having some issues with the footer but that's nothing new. Once that's sorted I imagine all will function as it should.