# How to sort Names (Li element - Javascript)

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with this?

```
window.onload = init; 


function init(){
    var button = document.getElementById("Submit"); //ask the document to return the element with id commentSubmission
    button.onclick=KeyPress; //when the button is clicked, the function validate is called
}


function KeyPress() {

    var visitorname = document.getElementById("name");
    var visitorcomment = document.getElementById("comment");
    var name = visitorname.value; //get the value of the object
    var comment = visitorcomment.value;
    var flag=0; //use to validate if the textboxes contain data

    if (name==null || name=="") {
        alert("Please Enter Name, Name Field is blank"); // This displays an error in terms of alert if name has not been input
        flag = 1; // Flag increments to one thus final if statement cannot be executed
    }

    if (comment==null || comment=="") {
        alert("Please Enter Comment, Comment field is blank");
        flag = 1;
    }

    if (flag==0){
        var finalComment = (name +" : " + comment); //concatenate the variable to form the output
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.innerHTML = finalComment; //inserting the content of the variable finalcomment in the object li
        var ul = document.getElementById("**listofcomments"**); //using variable ul as an object
        ul.appendChild(li); //including the li object in the ul object
    }
}
```

There are two input field name and comment 
and by making use of getElementById , im allowing multiple comments while the submit button is clicked

Can anyone help me to sort these comments

the comments are associated with the object **listofcomments**

**I need help to sort it in a way that if the same person comments twice,
the name of the person would appear below each other**

Comment: Can you provide a working JsFiddle?

Comment: any reason you are not using Jquery? It makes life a lot simpler for things like this. See this for a answer to a similar problem with Jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7251302/1033684

Comment: [Why is can someone help me not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your comments in a array of objects, you could use [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function to sort an array by a property.

In this demo, I'm using a compare function as parameter in the sort function to return a sorted array of comments by `name`.

> **Parameters:**
>
> **compareFunction:** Specifies a function that defines the sort order. If omitted, the array is sorted according to each character's Unicode
>   code point value, according to the string conversion of each element.

You can see how this demo works.

Hope this helps.

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  var button = document.getElementById("Submit");
  button.onclick = KeyPress;
}

var comments = []; // Array of comments.

function KeyPress() {
  var name, comment;
  name = document.getElementById("name");
  comment = document.getElementById("comment");

  // Validate fields and focus the control when is empty.
  if (name.value.length === 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Name, Name Field is blank");
    name.focus();
    return;
  }
  if (comment.value.length === 0) {
    alert("Please Enter Comment, Comment field is blank");
    comment.focus();
    return;
  }

  // Adds a comment in the comments array. A comment object has a name and comment property.
  comments.push({
    name: name.value,
    comment: comment.value
  });
  sortComments(); // Sort comments by name.

}

function sortComments() {
  comments.sort(function(a, b) { // Compare function.
    return a.name > b.name;
  });
  printComments();
}

function printComments() {
  var i, len = comments.length,
    comment = {},
    list = "<ul>";
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    comment = comments[i];
    list += "<li>"; // Creates the LI tag for every sorted comment in comments Array.
    list += comment.name;
    list += ": ";
    list += comment.comment;
    list += "</li>";
  }
  list += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("listofcomments").innerHTML = list;

}
```

```html
<p>Name:<input id="name" type="text" />
</p>
<p>Comment:
  <textarea id="comment"></textarea>
</p>
<p><button id="Submit">Submit</button></p>
<ul id="listofcomments"></ul>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept this answer to help to others users with similar issues. :)